# Disable Resize functionality in the Jqgird popup window

Tags: jqgrid

In Jqgrid,

i have a edit options and when we click on the edit option, it is defaulted with Resize option at the right down corner. 
I want to disable that functionality. Because if we resize the window and close and re-open the edit popup it is in the size were we changed. Highlighted the area in below image.

[image]

So i want to disable that functionality. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it only possible with jqDnR plugin ?? @oleg

Answer (score 0):

Oops it is simply worked. When i set the resize property to False.

Sorry. I tried with reSize. So it was not worked.

[Form Edit options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)